# Stack.sh failed Pike (DevStack)

Tags: 18.04, openstack

Stack.sh failed Pike

I am trying to deploy OpenStack on a virtual machine with Ubuntu version 18.04.4 on latest VirtualBox version

Stack.sh installation fails with this message

```
//git.openstack.org/openstack/keystone.git/opt/stack/keystone --branch stable / pike
Cloning into '/opt/stack/keystone' ...
warning: redirecting to https://opendev.org/openstack/keystone.git/
fatal: Remote branch stable / pike not found in upstream origin
+ functions-common: git_timed: 613 [[128 -ne 124]]
+ functions-common: git_timed: 614 die 614 'git call failed: [git clone' https://git.openstack.org/openstack/keystone.git/opt/stack/keystone --branch 'stable/pike]'
+ functions-common: die: 186 local exitcode = 0
+ functions-common: die: 187 set + o xtrace
[Call Trace]
./stack.sh:864:stack_install_service
/opt/stack/devstack/lib/stack: 32: install_keystone
/opt/stack/devstack/lib/keystone: 525: git_clone
/opt/stack/devstack/functions-common: 538: git_timed
/opt/stack/devstack/functions-common: 614: die
[ERROR] /opt/stack/devstack/functions-common: 614 git call failed: [git clone https://git.openstack.org/openstack/keystone.git/opt/stack/keystone --branch stable/pike]
Error on exit
World dumping ... see /opt/stack/logs/worlddump-2022-08-29-165121.txt for details
```

as I solve, it fails at Keystone cloning

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: why do you have so many spaces around '/'? Take those out

Comment: aside from that, the `pike` branch does not exist. which is exactly what the error is telling you. I'm not sure what's unclear. https://opendev.org/openstack/keystone/branches

Comment: Can it be solved?

Comment: depends what you're trying to do. Do you know how git works at all? If not, maybe learn that. Or find a better tutorial. What are you even trying to do? why did you choose that branch specifically?

Comment: I don't know much how Git works

Comment: If you do not wish to learn about how git works and how openstack works, then you will need to find a better tutorial that gives instructions that will actually work

Comment: What if I clone the repository from that URL?

Comment: what url? opendev.org/openstack/keystone.git? That will clone all branches, if that's what you want.

Comment: yes, My intention is just to try to fix this error

Comment: I assume your intention is to get a working version of openstack running, not to fix the error. Fixing the error != getting your end result, if you are running a command that doesn't get you what you want!

Comment: I've never had experience with DevStack, it never worked for me

Comment: First, you need to determine exactly what you want to do, and then find a procedure that does what you want. And then, you can fix errors. Right now, you are looking for a branch that doesn't exist. Why did you choose that branch? Because of a tutorial? then find a better tutorial. Pulled it out of nowhere? Do research to figure out which branch you want.

Comment: OKI get it, however I have tried other tutorials but it didn't go smoothly, what I want to do is get OpenStack on Ubuntu via DevStack

Comment: why don't you follow the directions made by the developers, https://docs.openstack.org/devstack/latest/ ?

Comment: and if you get stuck at a certain step, you can ask a question here, and be very clear exactly which step of those directions you got stuck on. That way, we don't waste time asking tons of questions about exactly what you did, etc.

Comment: Also, according to the devstack developers, Focal Fossa (20.04) is recommended, not 18.04 (which will reach end of support within the year anyways)